# What to do when transparency key fails?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I've created custom image in photoshop which I wanted to use as my Windows Form shape. I've set Windows form background color to the same color as transparency key, but when I run application large portion of that background color is not transparent as you can see on this picture:

[image: Picture]

What's the reason of this issue and how can it be fixed? Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you're using to create a shaped window. Also that image looks like it has an 8-bit alpha channel rather than 1-bit indexed transparency, are you certain you saved it in the correct format?

Comment: @Dai Hmm the way I did it is to set background image of form to this transparent PNG image and set the form background color to the same color as transparency key. I'm not using any aditional code. I thought I didn't have to. Also, about image format, I did not pay attention actually, I just saved it as png to keep image transparency background.

Comment: You can have one tranparent color but you can't have a blended tranparency.

Comment: Photoshop and Winforms don't like each other much.  Per-pixel alpha transparency is not directly supported.  You can turn it on with pinvoke but then you'll see a lot more stuff getting transparent beyond your image.  Like a lot of controls in the toolbox, including those listboxes.

Comment: It's been a long time since I said this... `Could you please point me in the right direction?` - Yes. **Forget dinousaur winforms and use modern technology.**... Ahh, it feels so refreshing. Thanks

Comment: @HighCore I disagree with you about WinForms being "dinosaur" technology - WinForms is a first-class tool, but, granted: only when used appropriately.

Comment: I found and used AlphaForms from CodeProject instead of normal forms, now it works like a charm. Btw, which new technology would you suggest for desktop apps then? :)

Comment: @Smola WPF of course for Windows desktop app, and the family of XAML based technologies. No amount of horrible winforms hacks and codeproject libs written by anonymous hippies can compare to built-in hardware acceleration and DirectX based rendering. if Hans Passant is saying that this is not supported, then I seriously doubt you or anyone else can come up with a proper solution. He's probably one of the highest authoritative voices here when it comes to winforms. BTW, anyone calling winforms a "first-class tool" has ever hardly used a modern UI framework. Or even HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this happened to me because shadings my image dropped over transparency key color changed the actual background color even if it was only for a bit and could not be seen by human eye. That's the real reason it wasn't recognized as transparency color, but thanks to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms) project, I managed to get the looks I wanted. Now my code generator looks "awesome". I started learning WPF, but there are many people on the internet talking that WPF is dead. Now I'm not even sure what most of the companies are using for their desktop apps.. well, nevermind. Thanks once again to the creator of Alpha Blended winforms and thank you guys for help! If anyone wanted to see final look of the forms here it is:

**Connection:**

[image]

**Main window:**

[image]

Comment: It is not much of an answer.  At least link to the code that you used so the next guy won't use dead WPF in desperation ;)  If you used what I *think* you used then you'd better test it on an older Windows version.

Comment: This is for personal use only app, it looks and works fine in Windows 8 so I'm satisfied :)